# Efficient SQL Bucket Sort based on Length of Substring Match

Tags: c#, sql, bucket-sort

Given a SQL database table containing strings indexed alphabetically, how might I perform a search query that orders by substring match?

For example, given the data set:

```
bad
banana
bandana
banker
bed
brother
```

And the search string `band`, I would expect the results ordered as follows

```
bandana (index 0-3 matched)
banana  (index 0-2 matched)
banker
bad     (index 0-1 matched)
bed     (index 0 matched)
brother
```

Note that we only care about the length of the substring matched. The matches that fall into each bucket **don't have to be sorted alphabetically, I only care about the bucket they fall into**.

So I guess naively the problem involves:

1. Seeing the length of substring match against my input for each row
2. Putting each row into the appropriate bucket based on the match length
3. Ordering the buckets in a descending order, ie (4 chars matched, 3 chars matched, 2..)

But this sounds expensive, so how could I implement this in SQL or C#, and do it efficiently?

Is there a similar problem/pattern I could benefit from here?

Many thanks

Comment: can you share what algorithm you use to perform the actual string match?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions as I'm still formulating the code in my head at this stage. It would have to be something with desirable complexity where run time takes precedence over memory used

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the most efficient way but.

Using a numbers table, split the strings into chars and join this to a split of the search string then just order by count and the string.

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE ( string VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO @t (string)
VALUES 
    ('bad'),
    ('banana'),
    ('bandana'),
    ('banker'),
    ('bed'),
    ('brother')

DECLARE @search VARCHAR(50) = 'band'

;WITH numbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.number) AS n
    FROM master..spt_values t1 
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
)   
SELECT string
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(t.string, numbers.n, 1) c, n
    FROM numbers
    WHERE numbers.n <= LEN(string)
) s1
JOIN (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@search, numbers.n, 1) c, n
    FROM numbers
    WHERE numbers.n <= LEN(@search)
) s2 ON s2.c = s1.c
    AND s2.n = s1.n 
GROUP BY string
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, string
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12398)

Comment: Thanks indeed! Admittedly some of the constructs are beyond my SQL knowledge! Im assuming to limit the results set I could change the 10000? Also what is the complexity of this solution relative to the input length and table size?

Comment: The numbers table could certainly be limited to `TOP (LEN(@search))`. I think the complexity  (ignoring the numbers table generation and only generating a sequence upto the length of the search string) is crudely something like `O(n*m)+O(n+m)+O(2n)` but tbh I'm not very knowledgeable at calculating complexity and there's lots of considerations e.g. indexes etc

Answer (score 0):

String operations and sql-server is not the best match afaik.

My best bet would be to try a modified version of the Bayer-Moore-horspool to find the number of matching characters. However, on a miss you wouldn't skip the full word length, only the length of the maximum match. Then simply insert into the appriate bucket.